# WCF service not behaving concurrently

Tags: wcf

I have a service code like:

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    void MyOperation1();
}
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class service1 : IService1
{
    public service1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("creating instance");
    }
    public void MyOperation1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting..");
        Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Ending..");
    }
}
```

My Client code looks like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread[] t = new Thread[10];
        NetTcpBinding myBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
        EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8000/MyService");
        ChannelFactory<IService1> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
        IService1 instance = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            t[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() 
            {
                instance.MyOperation1();
            }));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            t[i].Start();
        }          
    }
```

I am getting an output (where the calls are executed one by one):

```
creating instance
starting..
3
Ending..
starting..
3
Ending..
starting..
12
Ending..
starting..
3
Ending..
starting..
12
Ending..
starting..
3
Ending..
starting..
12
Ending..
starting..
3
Ending..
starting..
12
Ending..
starting..
3
Ending..
```

I am expecting all the calls to start parallely like this:

```
creating instance
starting..
starting..
starting..
starting..
3
Ending..
4
6
Ending..
```

Answer (score 4):

It is probably due to you using a single client (channel) instance.

The new threads that you create must wait for the previous thread to release the channel before it can use it.

Comment: Ok .. In that case how to achieve concurrency with one session?